# jQuery algorithm of $.get

Tags: jquery

I can't understand the flow of $.get function

Code 1 the click function is working and html

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    value = "Sentence";

    $.get("php.php", function(data){

        }, "json").done(function(data){

        value = data;

        $('#print').html(value[0]);

        $('a').click(function(){      //working if inside the done function
            alert($(this).attr('value'));
        }); 
    });
});
```

Code 2 if i put the click function outside done

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    value = "Sentence";

    $.get("php.php", function(data){

    }, "json").done(function(data){

        value = data;

    });

    $('#print').html(value[0]);       //problem here

        $('a').click(function(){
            alert($(this).attr('value'));
        }); 
});
```

Please help me to explain this

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Comment: You are dealing with asynchronous call..

Comment: So I can't use code 2? right?